# A problem handling Django stripe payment exceptions

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

> I have an exception handling problem for Django stripe payment, when I do input stripe, an exception error occurs, so it cannot be saved to the database

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # django crispy
    'crispy_forms',
    # django countries
    'django_countries',
    # init core
    'core',
    # stripe
    'stripe',
]
```

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
import stripe
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEYS

class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request, "payment.html")

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order   = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        token   = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        amount  = int(order.get_total() * 100)

        try:
            # Use Stripe's library to make requests...
            charge  = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=amount, # sen
                currency="usd",
                source=token
            )

            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.user = self.request.user
            payment.amount = order.get_total()
            payment.save()


            order.ordered   = True
            order.payment   = payment
            order.save()

            message.success("Your order successfully")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught
            body    = json_body
            err     = body.get('error', {})
            messages.error(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
            # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
            messages.error(self.request, "Rate limit error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            messages.error(self.request, "Invalid parameter")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
            # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            messages.error(self.request, "Not authenticated")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
            # Network communication with Stripe failed
            messages.error(self.request, "Network error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            # yourself an email
            messages.error(self.request, "Something wrong, please try again")
            return redirect("/")

        except Exception as e:
            # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            messages.error(self.request, "a serious error, we have been notified")
            return redirect("/")
```

> for the results of entering the stripe field is Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe. thank you for helping answer

Comment: what error are you seeing? is the error thrown by `charge  = stripe.Charge.create` or when you save to the datatbase `payment.save()`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the test_token in your payment page and match it with your STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEYS